# twisted-iocpsupport error when using pip on ubuntu / debian io.h missing

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, twisted

Receiving error:

```
 Building wheel for twisted-iocpsupport (PEP 517): started
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /usr/bin/python3 /tmp/tmpv8s6qz76 build_wheel /tmp/tmp9l8hgcva
       cwd: /tmp/pip-install-qsr4j4x_/twisted-iocpsupport
  Complete output (13 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_ext
  building 'twisted_iocpsupport.iocpsupport' extension
  creating build
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/twisted_iocpsupport
  x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -Itwisted_iocpsupport -I/usr/include/pyth
on3.8 -c twisted_iocpsupport/iocpsupport.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/twisted_iocpsupport/iocpsupport.o
  twisted_iocpsupport/iocpsupport.c:631:10: fatal error: io.h: No such file or directory
    631 | #include "io.h"
        |          ^~~~~~
  compilation terminated.
  error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for twisted-iocpsupport
  Building wheel for twisted-iocpsupport (PEP 517): finished with status 'error'
```

with

```
channels==3.0.3
daphne==3.0.1
Twisted==21.2.0
twisted-iocpsupport==1.0.1
```

In a docker environment:

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install python3 python3-pip

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Copy requirements
COPY requirements.txt ./

RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
```

also no chance on `python:3.8` or `debian:10.8`
including `python-dev` in the `apt` command also does not help.

Not sure what type of `io.h` file is required and how to obtain it. On google nothing really pops up and in the 2500 open issues on twistedmatrix, I cannot find anything related to this. The release seems to be from today 1st March 2021. Same error on `1.0.0`

Answer (score 35, accepted):

twisted-iocpsupport is a package providing bindings to the Windows "I/O Completion Ports" APIs.  These are Windows-only APIs.

You cannot use this package on Debian.  Fortunately, you also don't need to as you have access to a good Linux-based non-blocking I/O system - epoll - which is supported in Twisted without the use of any additional packages.

Comment: it solved the issue by removing the package from requirements.txt but the problem is when I create requirements on my development environment (windows) and use the same requirements on deployment server (debian) pip throws error is there any way to ignore this package even it is available in the requirements.txt

Comment: If you use a recent Twisted then you don't need to declare a twisted-iocpsupport dependency at all (I'm not sure you ever did).  Twisted depends on it.  You depend on Twisted.  pip installs what you need.

Comment: yeah it automatically installed twisted-iocpsupport but i got around it by using pip-chill instead of pip freeze

Comment: pip-chill is actually chill to use. rather than dumping every package name it just dumps the parent packages, thus reduces cross-platform issues.

Answer (score 0):

if you are working on Amazon Linux Platform 2 then also it is not needed that twisted package dependencies it will throw error if you have used it in your dependencies as per screenshot given below .

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BERH2.png)