# Failed building wheel for twisted-iocpsupport

Tags: python, django, docker, twisted, daphne

I'm trying to dockerize my django project. When i run "docker build -t django_project" i get following error:

```
18.82   Building wheel for twisted-iocpsupport (pyproject.toml): started
19.23   Building wheel for twisted-iocpsupport (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'error'
19.24   error: subprocess-exited-with-error
19.24
19.24   × Building wheel for twisted-iocpsupport (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
19.24   │ exit code: 1
19.24   ╰─> [13 lines of output]
19.24       running bdist_wheel
19.24       running build
19.24       running build_ext
19.24       building 'twisted_iocpsupport.iocpsupport' extension
19.24       creating build
19.24       creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39
19.24       creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/twisted_iocpsupport
19.24       gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -Itwisted_iocpsupport -I/usr/local/include/python3.9 -c twisted_iocpsupport/iocpsupport.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/twisted_iocpsupport/iocpsupport.o
19.24       twisted_iocpsupport/iocpsupport.c:1210:10: fatal error: io.h: No such file or directory
19.24        1210 | #include "io.h"
19.24             |          ^~~~~~
19.24       compilation terminated.
19.24       error: command '/usr/bin/gcc' failed with exit code 1
19.24       [end of output]
19.24
19.24   note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
19.24   ERROR: Failed building wheel for twisted-iocpsupport
19.24 Successfully built autobahn
19.24 Failed to build twisted-iocpsupport
19.24 ERROR: Could not build wheels for twisted-iocpsupport, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
19.70
19.70 [notice] A new release of pip is available: 23.0.1 -> 23.3.1
19.70 [notice] To update, run: pip install --upgrade pip
------
Dockerfile:13
--------------------
  11 |     # Copy the requirements file into the container and install the Python dependencies
  12 |     COPY requirements.txt /app/
  13 | >>> RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt --no-dependencies
  14 |
  15 |     # Copy the entire project directory into the container
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt --no-dependencies" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1
```

My requirements.txt:

```
asgiref==3.7.2
attrs==23.1.0
autobahn==23.6.2
Automat==22.10.0
cffi==1.16.0
channels==4.0.0
constantly==23.10.4
cryptography==41.0.5
daphne==4.0.0 
Django==4.2.7
hyperlink==21.0.0
idna==3.4
incremental==22.10.0
pyasn1==0.5.0
pyasn1-modules==0.3.0
pycparser==2.21
pyOpenSSL==23.3.0
python-decouple==3.8
service-identity==23.1.0
six==1.16.0
sqlparse==0.4.4
Twisted==23.10.0
twisted-iocpsupport==1.0.4
txaio==23.1.1
typing_extensions==4.8.0
tzdata==2023.3
zope.interface==6.1
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.9.18

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
ENV DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE django_project.settings  

WORKDIR /app

COPY requirements.txt /app/
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

COPY . /app/

EXPOSE 8000

CMD ["gunicorn", "django_project.wsgi:application", "--bind", "0.0.0.0:8000"]
```

Python version 3.9.18.

The problem is that daphne is trying to install the twisted-iocpsupport dependency. How to fix it and dockerize django project?

UPD:
added Dockerfile

Comment: Please share your Dockerfile in order to make it a [mre].

Comment: Does this answer your question? [twisted-iocpsupport error when using pip on ubuntu / debian io.h missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66428469/twisted-iocpsupport-error-when-using-pip-on-ubuntu-debian-io-h-missing)

Comment: Unfortunately no

Comment: How so? Just drop this requirements, it is a Windows only dependancy, as pointed in the other question, so you won't need it in your Debian image (python:3.9.18 is a from Debian bookworm base image).

Comment: I'm not familiar with Debian and just downloaded Docker. Do i need to delete twisted-iocp  from the requirements.txt file?

Comment: Yes, indeed. If you want to run that natively on windows too, you could condition the requirement to your platform too: [`twisted-iocpsupport==1.0.4; sys.platform == 'win32'`](https://peps.python.org/pep-0508/#environment-markers)

Comment: Thank you. I ran it as you said. There were no errors, but when I go to 127.0.0.1:8000 some of my templates are without styles. And also websocket not working. However when i run python manage.py runserver everything works as it supposed to be. Is this a Docker issue? Or is it because I removed this package?

Comment: @Denzel I think there is some other issue. When you say "websocket not working", what do you mean? What is the error you're experiencing?

Comment: No error messages were displayed. I don't know what the problem was. However, everything worked when I added docker-compose.yaml and ran it via docker-compose up

Comment: Ahh! Was your message broker (Redis, rabbitMQ) down perhaps?

Comment: I don't know for sure. If they are not built into django, then no. I didn't use them in my project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ehh; I normally just delete that dependency from the requirements.

It's not really nescessary.
I don't know why; probably some missing libraries on linux, but it always fails on Docker. Removing it is quick and dirty, but it works.